# Layer style choice?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-plugins, vector, style

In QGIS I would like to have the option of choosing the style of a vector layer without opening the layer properties panel. I would like to be able to choose it through a dialog window where I can choose the various columns in the attribute table, for example, to categorize my vector.

Is there a method, or a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In newer QGIS versions, you can use the Layer Styling Panel, which you can find at the top of the Layers Panel. Click the painbrush icon to activate it, and again, if you want to deactivate it.

[image]